# Unable to create a BehaviourSubject

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am unable to create a `BehaviourSubject`

I am expecting a `json` which should map to the following `Typescript` class

```
export class GetDataAPI {
  'some-data':string;
  constructor (public title:string,
               public description:string,
               public tags:Array<string>,
               public someData:string
             ){
    this['some-data'] = someData;
  }
}
```

In my code, I have created a `BehaviourSubject` as like follows:

```
private dataSubject: BehaviorSubject<GetDataAPI>;
```

When I try to initialise the `BehaviourSubject`, I get compilation error `this.dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<GetDataAPI>({});`

The error is `error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetDataAPI'.
  Property ''some-data'' is missing in type '{}'.`

Comment: try: `this.dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<GetDataAPI>({'some-data':''});`

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an object specifying all the arguments i.e.

```
new BehaviorSubject<GetDataAPI>({'some-data':'',
      'title':'',
  'description':'',
  'tags':[],
  'someData':''});
```

Comment: If `GetDataAPI` is a class, what you've done is still incorrect, as the subject's initial value won't be a class instance; it'll be an anonymous object.

Comment: so I should do `new BehaviorSubject<GetDataAPI>(new GetDataAPI('','',[],''))`? I just did and it works as well but I suppose your suggestion is the correct way than what I did earlier.

Comment: If it's a class, you have to ensure the constructor is called. Basically, you should not treat classes as if they are interfaces.

Comment: sorry, I am a bit confused now. Could you please give an example of how I should initialize if `new BehaviorSubject<GetDataAPI>(new GetDataAPI('','',[],''))` is incorrect. `GetDataAPI` is a class

Comment: I should have prefixed the previous comment with "yes", as your using `new GetDataAPI` etc. is how you need to do it. Sorry for making things confusing.

Comment: No problem. Happy to accept your answer if you could provide one